# Spring Boot Oauth2 Retrieving access token There is no client authentication. Try adding an appropriate authentication filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

Here's my Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class Application {

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/user" }, produces = "application/json")
    public Map<String, Object> user(OAuth2Authentication user) {
        Map<String, Object> userInfo = new HashMap<>();
        userInfo.put("user", user.getUserAuthentication().getPrincipal());
        userInfo.put("authorities", AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(user.getUserAuthentication().getAuthorities()));
        return userInfo;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }


}
```

WebSecurityConfigurer.java

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception {
        return super.userDetailsServiceBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("john.carnell").password("password1").roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("william.woodward").password("password2").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }
}
```

My Oauth2Config

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("eagleeye")
                .secret("thisissecret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("refresh_token", "password", "client_credentials")
                .scopes("webclient", "mobileclient");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
}
```

I am trying to retrieve an access token though POSTMAN however, this error keeps showing up

```
{
  "error": "unauthorized",
  "error_description": "There is no client authentication. Try adding an appropriate authentication filter."
}
```

These are values I'm passing in through POSTMAN

[image]

[image]

What am I missing on my config?